# I can't position the image outside the div

Tags: html, css, web

``I have set a division position to absolute and its parent to relative.
When I type top:-2px, then instead of going up outside the div, the 2px of the image is cut and the image remains inside the div.
I can't figure out why the image is not going outside the div.
[The image is not going outside the division even after writing top:-2px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6NFK5.png)

This is sass:

```
.composition{

position: relative;

&__photo{
    width: 55%;
    box-shadow: 0 1.5rem 4rem rgba($color-black,.4);
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: absolute;

    &--1{
        left: 0;
        top: -2rem;

    }

    &--2{
        top: 2rem; 
        right: 0;
    }

    &--3{
        top: 10rem;
        left: 20%;
    }
}
```

}

```
.row{
width: $grid-width;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: auto;


&:not(:last-child){
    margin-bottom: $gutter-vertical;}


[class^="col-"]{
    float: left;

    &:not(:last-child){
        margin-right: $gutter-horizontal;
    }
}

.col-1-of-2{
    width: calc((100% - #{$gutter-horizontal}) / 2);

}

.col-1-of-3{
    width: calc((100% - 2* #{$gutter-horizontal})/3);
}
```

}

This is html:

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="col-1-of-2">
                    <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-botton-small">You're Going To Fall In Love With Yoga</h3>
                    <p class="paragraph"></p>
                
                    <h3 class="heading-tertiary u-margin-botton-small">practice yoga like never before</h3>
                    <p class="paragraph">..</p>
                    <a href="" class="btn-txt">Learn More &rarr;</a>
                </div>
                
                <div class="col-1-of-2">
                    <div class="composition">  
                        <img src="img/nat-1-large.jpg" alt="photo 1" class="composition__photo composition__photo--1">
                        <img src="img/nat-2-large.jpg" alt="photo 2" class="composition__photo composition__photo--2">
                        <img src="img/nat-3-large.jpg" alt="photo 3" class="composition__photo composition__photo--3">
                    </div>
                </div>
           </div>
```

Comment: Hello can you provide a code snippet, that we can help you?

Comment: could you share your code with us please? inside a working snippet if possible

Comment: also the `postition relative` parent, does it have `overflow:hidden`?

Comment: I would recommend looking at these css properties: `display: block;` `display: inline-block;` `float: left;` `float: right;` `position: absolute;` `position: relative;`. One thing that also makes Grid systems a worry of the past is to either utilize Flexbox or Bootstrap (which is a very powerful CSS Framework that also utilizes Flexbox). You can Google all that with ease.

Comment: parent have property: overflow: auto

Comment: @GeekyPerson please include all relevant code. People cannot assist you otherwise. People can't magically come up with your code or how your approach has been. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and edit your question to follow those guidelines.

Comment: maybe its a z-index/display: block/position: relative on the img  problem, pls provide a code snippet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would want your image to go outside of your div but, i think your problem is with the div being set to "Absolute". Try either changing it to "relative" or/and change the padding to "padding-bottom" and how ever many pixels you need to move the image until it is outside of the div.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer. Thank you all for helping me with this.
So, the solution I found is:

Instead of writing -> `overflow: auto`

I wrote ->

```
`.row::after{
      content: "";
      clear: both;
      display: table;     
}`
```